# "Flatten" or pre-sort a multi-sort into a single sort

Tags: database, sorting, elasticsearch, ranking

Given an elastic search index or a normal SQL DB, that I have a multi-sort query on. Lets imagine I have 15 sort criterias for a single query. Is there a way I can flatten or pre-sort that 15 criterias to a single numeric value?

Example: Imagine a set of Product documents that is sorted

```
- By availability
- Then by sale percentage
- Then by remaining SKU
- Then by price
```

Can those sort criteria be converted into a numeric value for each document?
Lets say

```
ProductA
- Is available
- Sales is at 5%
- Remaining SKU = 10
- Price = 600

Has a numeric value of 10 (Very high order)

ProductB
- Is not available
- Sales is at 0%
- Remaining SKU = 0
- Price = 10000

Has a numeric value of 10000 (Very low order)
```

Then for any ProductC,D,E,F that is created later we can calculate its numeric value to immediately tell if ProductC is higher or lower order compared to all the other products

My understanding: That is my requirement seems to fall in a bespoke ranking algorithm more than sorting

My question: Is there an easy convert from multi-sort to a ranking score or "flatten" the sort... something like that or I would have to manually write all the score calculation code?